# Can I get Xbox One Games with Gold if I don't have an Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, xbox-one

Is this possible? I have a 360 but when I try to get the games for the One online it crashes on me.

Comment: I don't believe so, as you need to tie your account to a "home Xbox" before you can do remote download/installs. I'm not positive, though. so not answering.

Comment: What country are you from, respectively what country do you try to connect to xbox.com from. Also, what country is your profile tied to?

Answer (score 8):

You are able to get the free Xbox One games without the system, assuming you have an Xbox Live Gold account.

1. Go to the [Games with Gold](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/games-with-gold) page
2. Click the game you wish to "purchase"
3. Select "Buy Now"
4. Log in, if prompted
5. Double check that screen says "Free" (see image below)
6. Click "Confirm"

[image: Should say Free here]

**Note:** I do not own an Xbox One, nor have I ever had my account used on one.  I do have an Xbox 360 which my account is used on.  Additionally, my profile and system are both US region.  Not sure if that matters or if anyone with Xbox Live Gold can use this method.

**UPDATE:** After purchasing an Xbox One, I had used these steps to get 5 games onto my account.  When trying to download them, *you must have a non-trial Xbox Live Gold account for the installation to finish*.  That said, I can verify that getting the games through this method will be available for play when you setup an Xbox One with your account.

Comment: I'm getting this error though: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqvnyjr8mdjpnu2/Screenshot%202014-09-25%2020.20.19.png?dl=0

Comment: I'm not finding anything on those errors.  Are you sure you are logged in to your Xbox live gold account?

Comment: Could you state what region your profile hails from?

Comment: @EricTobias Added

Comment: I been doing this from the start although parental control accounts have to be done from an Xbox One.

Comment: I'm in the northeast

Comment: I go to log in to my account and then it gives me the error

Comment: @someone that sounds like an issue you might need to take up with Microsoft.  Does it also happen if you try logging in anywhere else?

Comment: Nope.  I'll contact Microsoft.